# ng2 animation: How to change css properties between states

Tags: javascript, angular, animation

I have a component with three animation states: `hidden`, `visible` and `switch`. The component starts in `hidden` and data is pulled from an API. When the API call is done, I set the state to `visible` and the component appears. If a user clicks on the component, the component disappears and new content is loaded from the API. Then the component re-appears.

This all works. But I want an effect that the component always flies in from the left and flies out to the right. I do this with `translateX(-200%)` and `translateX(200%)` - and `translateX(0)` for the visible state of course. I change the `opacity` from 0 to 1 for a nicer effect.

The problem: I need the component to go from `200%` to `-200%` between the states `switch` and `visible`. Otherwise it will (after the first time) fly in from the right and not from the left. And this needs not to be seen (opacity stays at 0).

I have tried `keyframes` but haven't managed to get a clean animation. Is there a way to change the starting point of an animation (style set) without a transition?

This is my animation code so far:

```
animations: [
  trigger('state', [
    state('hidden', style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-200%)'})),
    state('visible', style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
    state('switch', style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(200%)'})),
    transition('hidden => visible', animate('200ms 400ms ease-in-out')),
    transition('visible => switch', animate('200ms ease-in-out')),
    transition('switch => visible', [
      animate(400, keyframes([
        style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-200%)', offset: 0}),
        style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)',     offset: 0.4})
      ]))
    ])
  ])
]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else wondering: You can apply a style directly if you put the style function in the transition function. Like so:

```
  animations: [
    trigger('flyInAnimation', [
      state('hidden', style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'})),
      state('visible', style({transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
      state('switch', style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'})),
      transition('hidden => visible', animate('200ms 400ms ease-in-out')),
      transition('visible => switch', animate('200ms ease-in-out')),
      transition('switch => visible', [
        style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}),
        animate('200ms 600ms ease-in-out')
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

In the last transition.

The problem I had where I could see the in-between states and everything seemed not clean and well working disappeared as soon as I removed the `opacity` property from the other states and only directly applied it in the last transition (so that the move from right to left isn't visible). Apparently there where problems rendering this. Now everything works.